# How to convert hexadecimal date value to date value in hive

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, hex

I have timestamp column but the column is in string datatype but it contains actual date value in hexadecimal format as below. How to convert this hexadecimal date value into date value using hive

0x0000003D02E2CE75
0x0000000945EB44AE
0x0000000945EB44B0
0x0000000945EB44D3
0x00000008A11F0E9A
0x00000008A11F0ECF

Comment: which dates are there supposed to be? The values are too big for Hive unix_timestamp. Is it milliseconds? In this case it is 197x year

Comment: We are not sure about the value of the  hexadecimal in source. We need to convert this hexadecimal value to date value in format yyyy-mm-dd. We can ingore timestamp part. I'm not aware of this conversion before. When i tried to use the below i'm getting in 197X years i'm not sure whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) (use regexp_replace instead of replace for hive 1.1):

```
select 
    from_utc_timestamp(cast(conv(replace('0x00000008A11F0ECF', 'x', '0'), 16, 10) as bigint), 'PST')
```

Comment: AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: from_utc_timestamp(BIGINT, STRING).

Getting above error when executing above answer from User9123

Comment: @MuthuSamy, add your hive version to question

Comment: hive-1.1.0-cdh5.14.4

Comment: @MuthuSamy are you sure its hive? Its look like Impala exception

Comment: I tried in both Hive and Impala.

Hive Error:
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException line 0:undefined:-1 Invalid function 'replace'
Impala Error:
AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: from_utc_timestamp(BIGINT, STRING).
Seems replace function is not available in hive

Comment: I used translate function instead of replace function. select
    from_utc_timestamp(cast(conv(translate('0x00000002518F6594', 'x', '0'), 16, 10) as bigint), 'ACT') RESUT1970-04-26 09:41:26.74. But it too got failed in impala.Is there any way to query the same in Impala

Comment: @MuthuSamy Your question about hive or impala? It's not same. Create new question for impala

Comment: Ok . Sure. I will make separate question for Impala